# Wowza Error loading applications

Tags: wowza

I just restart my servered ( windows RS2012 ) then Wowza just crashed. Version 4.2. This error is on Applications tap

> Stack Trace Not Found (404) - Not Found at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.doError(ClientResource.java:599) at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handleInbound(ClientResource.java:1165) at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1060) at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1035) at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:937) at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.get(ClientResource.java:645) at com.wowza.wms.rest.WMSClientResource.get(Unknown Source) at com.wowza.wms.rest.ConfigBase.getObjectFromREST(Unknown Source) at com.wowza.wms.rest.vhosts.applications.ApplicationsConfig.getObjectFromREST(Unknown Source) at com.wowza.wms.webapp.application.ApplicationsController.getApplicationsJSON(ApplicationsController.java:37) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219) at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820) at net.winstone.core.ServletConfiguration.execute(ServletConfiguration.java:270) at net.winstone.core.SimpleRequestDispatcher.forward(SimpleRequestDispatcher.java:290) at net.winstone.core.SimpleRequestDispatcher.doFilter(SimpleRequestDispatcher.java:332) at com.wowza.wms.webapp.RequestLoggingFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggingFilter.java:35) at net.winstone.core.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:189) at net.winstone.core.SimpleRequestDispatcher.doFilter(SimpleRequestDispatcher.java:321) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260) at net.winstone.core.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:189) at net.winstone.core.SimpleRequestDispatcher.doFilter(SimpleRequestDispatcher.java:321) at com.wowza.wms.webapp.Utf8Filter.doFilter(Utf8Filter.java:35) at net.winstone.core.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:189) at net.winstone.core.SimpleRequestDispatcher.doFilter(SimpleRequestDispatcher.java:321) at net.winstone.core.SimpleRequestDispatcher.forward(SimpleRequestDispatcher.java:288) at net.winstone.core.listener.RequestHandlerThread.processRequest(RequestHandlerThread.java:213) at net.winstone.core.listener.RequestHandlerThread.run(RequestHandlerThread.java:144) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at net.winstone.util.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:81) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Can the server restart cause the wowza to crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not quite look like as if actually Wowza Streaming Engine would have crashed. This is just a stacktrace of the common HTTP 404 error that happens in the Engine Manager (separate application). It tries to talk to Streaming Engine at this point, but because you restarted that, you might need to wait a bit more for that to respond. You can try navigating back to the initial screen of the manager interface, or just hit F5 a bit later. Worst case you can restart the Engine Manager.

Comment: Thanks :) I just wanna be sure that is not a seriosly problem